# My Windows10 keeps waking up from sleep

Tags: windows-10, sleep, wake-up

My computer keeps waking up from sleep (while it's on battery). I checked quite a few key points to see what's causing this:

On battery, wake timers are disabled:

[image]

I have checked last wake reason:

```
powercfg/lastwake
Wake History Count - 0
```

And wake timers:

```
powercfg/waketimers
Timer set by [PROCESS] \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.Windows.StartMenuExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\StartMenuExperienceHost.exe expires at 00:00:00 on 쀀쾁♥.
```

I have no idea what is "StartMenuExperienceHost.exe".

I wish to achieve to disable *everything* from waking up my notebook on battery, as it constantly keeps discharging itself in my bag.

Answer (score 1):

`StartMenuExperienceHost` is your Start menu.
The only reason it would have to wake up your computer is probably the
Live Tiles.

To turn off live tiles in the Start menu, go to
*Settings > Personalisation > Start* and
toggle "Show More Tiles on Start" to Off.

Another method is to hit the Windows key and right-click on any of the
Live Tiles (like Photos, Mail, or Office),
then hover over "More" and click on "Turn Live Tile Off".

If this also fails, remove all these Live Tiles from the Start menu.

Reboot for any change to take effect.